# Average matrix values after interpolation

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix that is 1x24. Within each cell is another matrix that is a single column. However, the column length changes from one matrix to another. Is there a way to average the first row from each matrix, and output into a new matrix where the first cell is the average of all the matrix first cells? Then second and third all the way to the end?

Here is my script so far. You can see that I create a matrix. Now I would like to average them (after I interpolate them).

```
close all
clear
clc

k = cell(1,24);
for k=1:24
   data{k} = xlsread('C:\data.xlsx',['PKA', num2str(k)]);
end


for i=1:24
xfinal{i}=data{1,i}(end,1);
xi{i}=0:0.001:xfinal{i};
xi{i}=transpose(xi{i});

x{i}=data{1,i}(:,1);
y{i}=data{1,i}(:,4);

yi{i} = interp1(x{i},y{i},xi{i});

xf{i}=xi{i};
xf{i}=(1:10001);

yi{i} = interp1(x{i},y{i},xi{i});

yf{i}=yi{i};
yf{i}=(1:10001);
end
```

If I click on the yi variable, I see a single row. In each cell, there is another matrix. The first matrix is 10014x1, the second is 10084x1. I only care about the first 10,001 elements, despite the fact that the matrices are different lengths. I just want the first 10,000 elements averaged from each matrix. So row 1 is averaged, row 2, from each matrix, etc. , all in a single matrix that is 10001x1

EDIT: Code working with rayreng

```
close all
clear
clc




k = cell(1,24);
for k=1:24
   data{k} = xlsread('C:data.xlsx',['PKA', num2str(k)]);
end


for i=1:24
xfinal{i}=data{1,i}(end,1);
xi{i}=0:0.001:xfinal{i};
xi{i}=transpose(xi{i});

x{i}=data{1,i}(:,1);
y{i}=data{1,i}(:,4);



yi{i} = interp1(x{i},y{i},xi{i});

end

Y = zeros(10001, numel(data));
for ii = 1 : numel(data)
    Y(:, ii) = yi{ii}(1 : 10001);
end

Y2 = mean(Y, 2);

Y3 = std(Y2, [], 2); errorbar(0 : 0.1 : 10, Y2(1: 100 : 10001), Y3(1 : 100 : 10001));
grid on
```

Comment: Suppose you have a cell array that's three elements, and the elements are defined as column vectors with size `5 x 1`, `3 x 1` and `2 x 1`.  What do you do when you are in the third row, when you've exhausted the elements from the third matrix of `2 x 1`?  I can't seem to figure that out with your code as I don't know what the current structure is with your variables.

Comment: @rayryeng If I click on the yi variable, I see a single row. In each cell, there is another matrix. The first matrix is 10014x1, the second is 10084x1. I only care about the first 10,001 elements, despite the fact that the matrices are different lengths. I just want the first 10,000 elements averaged from each matrix. So row 1 is averaged, row 2, from each matrix, etc. , all in a single matrix that is 10001x1

Comment: What if you have a matrix that is less than 10000 elements?  Will that ever happen?  Your problem statement is still very ill-posed.  In addition, your desired output and the code you have posted do not correspond to each other.

Comment: @rayryeng None are less than 10000 elements. The code I posted has not yet attempted to calculate it. It just shows what I did to get to this current point to help the reader understand how my problem is setup. I have tried to do it myself but I can't seem to get it work.

Comment: Ah I see. OK.  Let me see what I can cook up.

Comment: @rayreng Probably a new variable could be created instead of yi so that they are all the same length. Just append every matrix in yi to stop at 10,001 elements.

Comment: @rayryeng I edited my code so they are all the same length. Now the values are under yf

Comment: You don't need to do that.  I'll handle it for the original problem.  BTW, `yf` isn't necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately because you have a cell array of data where each cell has different row lengths, you have no choice but to loop through each cell.  What's even more intricate is that you want to find the average of each position `i` over all cell arrays to be stored in an output array such that `Y(i)` contains the desired average.  Naively, you'd have to use a double `for` loop for that, but what I can recommend since you are guaranteed to have 10001 elements and that's relatively cheap in memory is to simply use a single `for` loop and create a new matrix that is 10001 elements long with the total number of columns being the total number of your cells.  You would then extract out the first 10001 elements of each column in your cell array and place it in its corresponding column in the output matrix.  Once you do that, just average along each row individually:

```
Y = zeros(10001, numel(data));
for ii = 1 : numel(data)
    Y(:, ii) = yi{ii}(1 : 10001);
end

Ymean = mean(Y, 2);
```

`Y` will contain a matrix of size `10001 x 24`, and we thus call `mean` along each row individually and transform `Y` to a `10001 x 1` column vector storing the mean of each position `i` for all cell arrays stored in `Ymean`.

Finally, you desire to draw an error bar graph where you wish to compute the standard deviation for each column of the matrix `Y` as well.  You will thus need to find the standard deviation of each row, then use it with the `[errorbar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/errorbar.html) function.  Specifically, given your `x` coordinates which you defined to be from `0` to `10` in steps of `0.001`, the `y` coordinates would be the mean of each row of `Y`, the error bars would be the standard deviation of each row of `Y`, and so the error bars drawn would be twice the standard deviation centered at each mean point.

Therefore:

```
Y = zeros(10001, numel(data));
for ii = 1 : numel(data)
    Y(:, ii) = yi{ii}(1 : 10001);
end

Ymean = mean(Y, 2);
Ystd = std(Y, [], 2);

errorbar(0 : 0.001 : 10, Ymean, Ystd);
```

This figure will be rather clustered as you have 10000 points to deal with.  Instead, try subsampling and perhaps show 101 points instead to get a feel of what you're visualizing:

```
errorbar(0 : 0.1 : 10, Ymean(1 : 100 : 10001), Ystd(1 : 100 : 10001));
```

In general, you can set a variable for the desired spacing in between each point, then subsample the `x` and `y` axes, as well as the lengths of each of the error bars to complete everything.

```
sampling_interval = 200;
pts = 1 : sampling_interval : 10001;
x = 0 : 0.001 : 10;
x = x(pts);
errorbar(x, Ymean(pts), Ystd(pts));
```

The first line of code defines the sampling interval, and we then define a vector from 1 up to 10001 increasing linearly by `sampling_interval` amount.  We then create the equivalent values for the `x` axis, and we finally plot everything.

Comment: You said that Y will contain a matrix of size 10,000x24 but I only see a single column. I understand you overwrote it with Y = mean(Y,2), but is there a way to see the matrix that was created?

Comment: Just change it to a different variable: `Y2 = mean(Y, 2);`.  `Y` will contain the original matrix.  I overwrote it because I didn't think you actually needed to see the matrix.  It was a means to an end.

Comment: I did that.  It still just shows that Y is 10,000x1

Comment: @Jack You need to run the code again from the beginning of the section.  You are just running the last command, and `Y` was already overwritten at that point.  Just run it from the `Y = zeros(...)` part, and make sure you change `Y = mean(Y, 2);` to `Y2 = mean(Y, 2);`.  Once you do this, `Y2` will contain your desired single column and `Y` will contain the first 10000 elements of each cell array - one per column.

Comment: Actually, it appears that Y=mean(Y,2) just gives me the exact first matrix values, not the mean. I did rerun it. The variable Y that is created is just the first matrix in yi

Comment: @Jack That's a problem with your inputs - nothing to do with the code I wrote.  You may want to recheck your interpolation code before you run the code I provided again.

Comment: All of my yi matrices are different. I am telling you that Y is just the first matrix. I don't think it has anything to do with interpolation. I have 24 unique matrices and the matrix that is created in your for loop is just the first matrix.

Comment: That is not what I mean. When I just get rid of the Y=mean command, I should have a matrix that is 10,000x24, but I dont. I just have a matrix that is 10,000x1.

Comment: Ah, that's because you overwrote `k` as a `for` loop index.  I've changed the code.  Try it again.  It tripped me out because I saw at the very beginning that you defined `k` as a cell array, but then you stored the data in `data` instead.  Serves me right that I didn't read the entire code... but again, that isn't my job.

Comment: Now I get a matrix that is 10,000x24 but only the first column has nonzero numbers. The values in columns 2-24 are all 0, despite the fact that each matrix in yi is nonzero

Comment: @Jack sorry. Forgot to change the `for` loop. Try it again.

Comment: @Jack You're welcome!  Glad we finally got it to work.

Comment: I hate to ask for more, maybe I should create a new question? Is there a quick way to plot it with the stdev of all the values? Should that be a new question? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Are you talking about a plot where you're plotting the bars of standard deviation combined with the mean... something like this? http://support.sas.com/kb/42/addl/fusion_42515_1_g42515.gif.  For that, you'd need to know the `x` axis values.  The `y` axis values would be the mean, and the error bars would simply be the standard deviation of each column in `Y`,  but what's important is the `x` axis.  Would this just be `1 : 10000`?

Comment: Right. I have my y values. My x values are just 10,000 elements from 0 to 10.

Comment: Right.  Well you can do that in two lines of code.  The `errorbar` function is your friend: `Y3 = std(Y, [], 2); errorbar((0 : 0.001 : 9.999).', Y2, Y3);`.  First line finds the standard deviation of each row in the stacked `Y` matrix we created, then we plot an error bar graph whose error lines are the size of the twice the standard deviation: `mean - std` to `mean + std`. 
 More documentation about it here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/errorbar.html

Comment: Is this assuming that we are using Y instead of Y2? Also the error bars are horizontal but they should be vertical since the y variable is what is dfiferent between each matrix

Comment: The error bars are by default vertical.  Not sure why you're seeing them horizontal.  Also, we should be using `Y2`, sorry not `Y`.

Comment: Yeah that is strange. Also, I want it to be to 10,000 not 9.999. But when I change the other variables to 10,001 and that to 10,000, i get that they are not the same length

Comment: @Jack Change the `for` loop so that it captures 10001 elements.  I'll change this in my code.

Comment: Also... you are plotting 10001 error lines, so it's definitely going to look messy.  That may be way you're confused.  Try plotting at an interval instead of all 10000... so perhaps try plotting only 101 of them: `errorbar(0 : 0.1 : 10, Y2(1: 100 : 10001), Y3(1 : 100 : 10001));`  This assumes you have 10001 elements now, instead of 10000.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that..I can change the number of elements once I get a feel for the code. Currently though, I keep getting errors. The error I get is this: Error using errorbar>checkSingleInput (line 264)
XData must be the same size as YData.

Error in errorbar (line 94)
x = checkSingleInput(x, sz, 'XData');

Error in interpolate (line 35)
Y3 = std(Y, [], 2); errorbar((0 : 0.001 : 10).', Y, Y3);

Comment: Replace `Y` with `Y2`.

Comment: But dont I need the stdev from Y? Y2 just has the already averaged values

Comment: That's stored in `Y3`.  The `x` coordinates are from 0 to 10, the `y` coordinates are the **averaged** values... that's in `Y2`.... and the length of the error bars are the standard deviations... that's in `Y3`.

Comment: How is that stored in Y3? Y3 only makes reference to Y2, never Y?

Comment: I thought you changed your code so that `Y2` stores the actual average.... that's where we keep messing up.  If you want the standard deviation, you'll need to remember the 24 column matrix you made.  I'll have to edit my post again.

Comment: @Jack I've just edited my post to put in exactly what you want.  This will minimize the conversation we have here.... and I have to get back to work.

Comment: Thanks for the help, seems to be working. Error bars are correct now. must have been an error in my code.

Comment: By default `errorbar` always provides vertical error bars... meaning that at each point, you draw a vertical error line.  There are small horizontal markers at the end of the line that are simply indicators that help you determine which values on the `y` axis they roughly stop at.

Comment: YOu had a good idea every 100 points. If I want to change it to every 200 points, do I just change the two 100 to 200? And then 0.1 to 0.2. seems like it works. thanks!

Comment: Yes, you'd also have to change the resolution of the `x` axis to go every 0.05 instead of 0.1.  I'll make my post more robust to this.

Comment: 0.2, not 0.05 i beleive

Comment: @Jack Ah I thought you wanted 200 points, not sample every 200 points.  Yes you're right.  I've added some more code in to make this adaptable to whatever spacing you want.